# Basis spin states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-spin, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian

We are given a system of $N$ spin states and the following (non-hermitian) Hamiltonian

$$H = \frac{N \hbar \nu}{2M} \sin(\alpha)+ \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{\hbar \omega_i }{2} \sigma_{z,i} + \frac{\hbar \nu \sin(\alpha)}{2M } \sum_{i=1}^N  \sum_{j=i-M, j \neq i}^{i+M} ( \sigma_{+,i} \otimes \sigma_{+,j} + \sigma_{z,i} \otimes \sigma_{z,j})$$

Now $\sigma_{z,i}$ is the pauli matrix belonging to the i-th particle and the spin z- direction. $\sigma_{\pm,i}$ is the spin matrix $\sigma_{x,i} \pm i \sigma_{y,i}$.

Now, I read that there is a matrix representation such that this Hamiltonian is an upper diagonal matrix with eigenvalues $ \pm \frac{\hbar \omega_i}{2} + k \frac{\hbar \nu}{2M} \sin(\alpha), k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Does anybody know how this basis might look like? Somehow I don't really trust the result, as there should not be an index $i$ down the diagonal, but I still think that there must be this basis such that this becomes an upper diagonal matrix.

Note, that this question is related to this arxiv paper (see page 2, equation (4)) [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1408.4585).

Comment: If you write out $H$ in terms of the Pauli matrices, it is already upper triangular. You can then read off the eigenvalues on the diagonal, i.e., by looking only at the $\sigma_z$s.

Comment: what do you mean by writing $H$ in terms of the Pauli matrices? Do you think you could elaborate on that?

Comment: How would you write $\sigma_{+}$ as a matrix? And how $\sigma_{+,i}\otimes \sigma_{+,j}$? How $\sigma_{z,i}\otimes \sigma_{z,j}$?

Comment: well I mean $\sigma_{+}$ is just addition of two $2x2$ matrices. From this I would calculate the tensor products using the Kronecker product. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product

Comment: I welcome any help on this, but you might also consider posting your hints as an answer.

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean, but isn't this Hamiltonian a little bit weird? I mean, the first term is a scalar, then we have a $2x2$ matrix in the second term and then a sum of $4x4$ matrices in the last term (due to the tensor product). How do I treat this correctly?

Comment: The Hamiltonian describes $N$ two-level systems, i.e., it is a $2^N\times 2^N$ matrix.  The point is that you have to "pad" the tensor product with identity matrices $I$, e.g., $\sigma_{+,i}\otimes\sigma_{+,j}\equiv I\otimes\dots\otimes I\otimes \sigma_{+,i}\otimes I\otimes\dots\otimes I\otimes \sigma_{+,j}\otimes I\dots$.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch ah, thank you. so in front of the first term is an imaginary $2^N \times 2^N$ identity matrix. Could you also give me a hint how to read the second term? Apparently, we have to fill in a few identity matrices there too.

Comment: The second term is $I_1\otimes \dots \otimes I_{i-1}\otimes \sigma_{z,i}\otimes I_{i+1}\otimes\dots$, and so further.  For each particle where there is no $\sigma$, you have to put a $2\times 2$ identity matrix.